# Find out till where a regex satisfies a sentence

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I have some sentence and a regular expression. Is it possible to find out till where in the regex my sentence satisfies. For example consider my sentence as `MMMV` and regex as `M+V?T*Z+`. Now regex till `M+V?` satisfies the sentences and the remaining part of regex is `T*Z+` which should be my output.

My approach right now is to break the regex in individual parts and store that in a list and then match by concatenating first n parts till sentence matches. For example if my regex is `M+V?T*Z+`, then my list is `['M+', 'V?', 'T*', 'Z+']`. I then match my string in loop first by `M+`, second by `M+V?` and so on till complete match is found and then take the remaining list as output. Below is the code

```
            re_exp = ['M+', 'V?', 'T*', 'Z+']
            for n in range(len(re_exp)):
                re_expression = ''.join(re_exp[:n+1])
                if re.match(r'{0}$'.format(re_expression), sentence_language):
                    return re_exp[n+1:]
```

Is there a better approach to achieve this may be by using some parsing library etc.

Comment: How complex can the regex be? Can it have groups, character groups, backreferences, lookaheads, etc.?

Comment: If the regex are very simple, as in your example, you _might_ even be able to write a very simple custom regex parser/matcher. Particularly if consecutive parts of the regex handle different characters (e.g. no `V?V+`) then this should even work greedily, without any backtracking.

Comment: The regex would be simple. But my only consideration in writing custom function is the speed difference and handling of end-cases as the size of regex increases. It would be helpful if I can tweak `re` itself to get the output or use some other parsing library

Comment: Maybe, instead of joining parts of the regex and then matching the entire string, you could just match one part and then match the next part to the remainder of the string, i.e. slicing away the prefix that matched the first "term" of the regex.

Comment: If a string matches `M+V?` then it also matches `M+V?T*`, since `T*` can match zero characters. So it's hard to see how a hypothetical partial matcher would ever report `M+V?` as a partial match.

Comment: @tobias_k that's indeed a better approach.

Comment: @rici that's why I am matching the string with regex parts instead of full regex at once. In that case the string should match with only first parts of regex till it satisfies. Whenever there is a match I should be able to return the remaining part of the regex. In your example the string would match with `M+V?` first and `T*` would be returned as output. Now it's upon me to permutate the output and generate sentences.

Comment: But the allowed follows for `MMMV` and `MMMVT` are identical; both can be followed by either `T` or `Z`. So one would expect that a partial-match regex engine would return the same thing in both cases.

Comment: Yes, but that will not be required for my case. I would only require the next follow regex. So the output for `MMMV` and `MMMVT` can be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your regex is rather simple, with no groups, backreferences, lookaheads, etc., e.g. as in your case, following the pattern `\w[+*?]?`, you can first split it up into parts, as you already do. But then instead of iteratively joining the parts and matching them against the entire string, you can test each part individually by slicing away the already matched parts.

```
def match(pattern, string):
    res = pat = ""
    for p in re.findall(r"\w[+*?]?", pattern):
        m = re.match(p, string)
        if m:
            g = m.group()
            string = string[len(g):]
            res, pat = res + g, pat + p
        else:
            break
    return pat, res
```

Example:

```
>>> for s in "MMMV", "MMVVTTZ", "MTTZZZ", "MVZZZ", "MVTZX":
>>>     print(*match("M+V?T*Z+", s))
...
M+V?T* MMMV
M+V?T* MMV
M+V?T*Z+ MTTZZZ
M+V?T*Z+ MVZZZ
M+V?T*Z+ MVTZ
```

Note, however, that in the worst case of having a string of length `n` and a pattern of `n` parts, each matching just a single character, this will still have O(n²) for repeatedly slicing the string.

Also, this may fail if two consecutive parts are about the same character, e.g. `a?a+b` (which *should* be equivalent to `a+b`) will not match `ab` but only `aab` as the single `a` is already "consumed" by the `a?`.

You could get the complexity down to O(n) by writing your own very simple regex matcher for that very reduced sort of regex, but in the average case that might not be worth it, or even slower.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `()` to enclose groups in regex. For example: `M+V?(T*Z+)`, the output you want is stored in the first group of the regex.

I know the question says python, but here you can see the regex in action:

```js
const regex = /M+V?(T*Z+)/;
const str = `MMMVTZ`;
let m = regex.exec(str);

console.log(m[1]);
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is I don't know before hand where the `()` would come. Think of it as this way, I need to tell user what should come after he/she has typed some sentence. The sentence can be `MMM`, `MMMV` etc. So the output varies in each case.